# Xamarin.Forms: create a Rounded/Circle Button from Iconize

Tags: android, button, fonts, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I try to create a **Rounded/Circle Button** that can display **font icons**. As I already use [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize) in my project, I tried to create the Rounded/Circle Button from the existing `IconButton`.

I first tried this, by fixing `BorderRadiusas` the half value of the `HeightRequest`/`WidthRequest`:

```
<iconize:IconButton HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" 
                    BorderRadius="20"
                    Text="fa-500px" TextColor="Red" FontSize="20" 
                    BackgroundColor="Orange" BorderColor="Red"
                    BorderWidth="2" 
                    VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
</iconize:IconButton>
```

***The default rendering works as expected on UWP, but the "clicked" rendering is not good, as a rectangle is appearing.
However on Android, the button is always in "default" mode: there is no border, no background, ...***

So I've added a **FlatButton** control, and a **Renderer** for Android:

```
public class FlatButton : IconButton
{
}

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FlatButton), typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]
namespace Iconize.Sample.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class FlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<controls:FlatButton HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" 
                    BorderRadius="20"
                   Text="fa-500px" TextColor="Red" FontSize="20" 
                   BackgroundColor="Orange" BorderColor="Red"
                   BorderWidth="2" 
                   VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
</controls:FlatButton>
```

***This time, the rounded rendering is fine on Android, but I've lost the "display" of the font icon.***

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screeshot]

***Is there a way to keep the rounded renderer and the icon display?
And in a second time, is there a way to fix the rendering issue on UWP when the button is clicked?***

I also looked other plugins:

- [Flexbutton](https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton): seems to work fine, but there is no UWP support
- [ButtonCirclePlugin](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/ButtonCirclePlugin): I wasn't able to use it in my solution, and the I wasn't able to built the provided sample...

***Would you have other suggestions?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a temporary solution, by redefining the Iconize `IconButtonRenderer` like this:

- [CircleIconButton](https://gist.github.com/Goldstrike/e18507cbb4c97b8533f07670c0eddf96#file-circleiconbutton-cs): I've created a control that inherits from `IconButton`
- [CircleIconButtonRenderer](https://gist.github.com/Goldstrike/e18507cbb4c97b8533f07670c0eddf96#file-circleiconbuttonrenderer-cs): I've duplicated the `IconButtonRenderer` for Android. I had to removed the first debug tests, and the expected new format of  constructor: `public CircleIconButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)`. So this class appears as "obsolete".
- [MainPage](https://gist.github.com/Goldstrike/e18507cbb4c97b8533f07670c0eddf96#file-mainpage-xaml): I've implemented the new control in the page, like we do for an `IconButton`.

But there is probably a better way, as the expected constructor is not implemented...